# Set icon and back button on action bar at same time in Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.icon); is not working in Android.

```
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Dictionary");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true); 
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_dictionary);
```

Comment: getSupportActionBar().setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_back)); Try to add this.

Comment: setNavigationIcon() is not a funcation .. Here it is giving error on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your case you should have a line of code before these lines...if you dont have this line that is the problem

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

however i myself use material toolbar and add icon and text to toolbar in xml and got rid of these methods! see one of my xml files for sample

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_back"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ripple_on_primary"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_back"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@id/iv_back"
                android:id="@+id/tv_toolbar"
                style="@style/tvTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/previous_transactions" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/tvContent"
                android:text="@string/help"
                android:id="@+id/tv_help"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```